# How to start another installed app in Android from my application?

Tags: android, android-intent

Hello guys I am new to android core apps but I love to do animation stuffs in Android. But what I want is I want to start another another app using my application. For eg. I want to start facebook app using my application. 
I dont know if the question is understood or not, but really need a clue on how to do such stuffs.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

In your case, you should check this apps package names and replace them.

It wouldn't be a bad idea to check if it's installed first :

```
private boolean isPackageInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check android's developer document about: Intent

refer to Context:
startActivity
startService
sendBroadcast